# Kudu table comments not showing up. What should I do?

Tags: impala, apache-kudu

This is my create statement for impala-shell:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp.demo0011(
  uid Bigint, comment'用户uid'
  nick String, comment'昵称'
  primary key(uid)
)
partition by hash(uid) partitions 128
stored as kudu
tblproperties (
  'kudu.master_addresses'='10.10.10.1'
);
```

When I enter `desc tmp.demo0011;` I get:

```
+------+--------+---------+
| name | type   | comment | 
+------+--------+---------+
| uid  | bigint |         | 
| nick | string |         |
+------+--------+---------+
```

The comment section is nothing.  Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I know why.

When I entered:

```
alter table demo0011 change uid uid bigint comment 'test comment';
```

I get:

> ERROR: AnalysisException: Kudu does not support column comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE test_db.babylist
(
    id INT COMMENT 'Comment of ID Column',
    patient_name STRING,
    mother_name STRING,
    Primary key (id)
)
PARTITION BY HASH(id) PARTITIONS 3 
COMMENT 'Comment of Table' 
STORED AS KUDU;

ALTER TABLE test_db.babylist CHANGE patient_name patient_name string COMMENT 'Comment of Column-patient_name';

DESCRIBE test_db.babylist;

ALTER TABLE test_db.babylist ALTER COLUMN id SET COMMENT 'Comment of Column-id';

DESCRIBE test_db.babylist

ALTER TABLE stest_db.babylist ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS father_name string;

DESCRIBE test_db.babylist;

ALTER TABLE test_db.babylist DROP COLUMN mother_name;

DESCRIBE test_db.babylist;

ALTER TABLE test_db.babylist ALTER COLUMN father_name SET COMMENT 'Comment of Column-father_name';
```

[image]